# Deleted "LocalLow" - Now Windows Feature not working

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've deleted the folder by mistake, and it was too large to go into the Recycling bin because I didn't have enough room so it was deleted, and I've restarted my PC since then.

However, now I'm unable to use the Start Menu, Open Images and a lot of other things aren't working, is there a way to fix this without having to re-install Windows 10.

I'm not sure why but I don't have any restore points, I thought I did.

Comment: Do you have any restore points saved?

Comment: @PFitz  Not that I'm aware of, and I've checked, but I remember backing it up, but it was back to when I first got the computer, I would much prefer an easier way

Comment: Do you mean that you've checked recently? Windows 10 creates restore points on its own during most updates and other events. Another options would be creating a new user profile then copying the contents from the new profile to the existing one.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that @PFitz Thanks, I'll see if I can do that.

Comment: @PFitz Should I copy the entire AppData Folder do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the help and the idea @PFitz turns out I deleted the Local Folder, so I've finally fixed it!